# How to create a circular image with a rectangular shape? CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to add a list of items beneath a circular image and the following is happening:

[image: problem]

I want the items to be aligned with each other.
Does anyone knows how to fix it?
The items are inside a container and each of them has the following `display: inline-block`

Here's the code for reference:

```css
*{
  align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
}
.container > div {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 33.3%;
}

#myImage {
 width: 70%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 13px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 13px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<img src="images/twitter.png" id="myImage">

      <div class="container">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>c</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added float left and it seems to be sitting right next to each other now. You can add padding/margin around the divs under container class to space it from above.

```css
        *{
          align-items: center;
         align-content: center;
         text-align: center;
         height: 100%;
         margin-top: 0px;
        }
        .container > div {
         display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: top;
         width: 33.3%;
          float:left;
        }
        

        #myImage {
         width: 70%;
         border-radius: 50%;
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 13px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
         box-shadow: 0px 13px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }
```

```html
        <img src="images/twitter.png" id="myImage">

              <div class="container">
                <div>a</div>
                <div>b</div>
                <div>c</div>
              </div>
```

Let me know if its working for you now.